# Drag-and-drop image out of notebook

Tags: front-end, image, mac-os-x, interface

Drag-and-dropping images into notebooks works like a charm. But oftentimes I already have an image in a notebook and I want to use somewhere outside Mathematica. So we do this: right-clicking and browsing to "save as" or writing a line of code using Export[]. Ok, but this usually takes 5-30 seconds and I find myself doing this over and over.

Being able to drag and drop the image from the notebook to a folder on my computer (specifically into OSX Finder and Chrome) would be extremely useful to me! Does anyone know if this is possible and if so who to enable it?

Comment: If you highlight the image and copy (command C) then you can paste it into applications like photoshop (command v).

Comment: I've used that before, cmd+C works for random apps, but I my most common application is to drop it into either: a finder or a browser window

Comment: Will the "Save Graphic As..." option work? You can get that via context click.

Comment: @MB1965 No, I mentioned in the problem. Basically I already have the window open and just want to drag it there.

Comment: @M.R. missed that line. I would doubt it's possible. When you drag and image from Chrome onto the desktop it just copies the file, but there is no file here to copy. But hopefully I'm proven wrong.

Comment: You could probably do this with NetLink or JLink.